# HttpPost method doesn't get the correct model from view, also get Null/Reference object errors with other objects - MVC 5 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, payment, checkout

I'm going to explain the issue as I go along.

I have this view here.

**View:**

```
@model Project.Models.CheckoutItem
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Checkout - Project</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ margin-top:20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm( ))
    {
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified thumbnail setup-panel">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#step-1">
                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Step 1</h4>
                            <p class="list-group-item-text">Your Details</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="disabled">
                        <a href="#step-2">
                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Step 2</h4>
                            <p class="list-group-item-text">Delivery Method</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="disabled">
                        <a href="#step-3">
                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Step 3</h4>
                            <p class="list-group-item-text">Payment Information</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Item: @Model.Item.ItemName
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

                        @Html.ValidationSummary()

                    <!-- STEP 1-->
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" }) <br/>

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })<br />

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })<br />

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNumber) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })<br />

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MsgOnCard) @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.MsgOnCard, new { @class = "form-control" })<br />

                            <button id="activate-step-2" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Next</button>

                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <!-- STEP 2 -->
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ShippingMeth) @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.ShippingMeth) <br/> <br/>

                        <div id="shippingDetails" class="disabled">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.deliveryDetails.Street)  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.deliveryDetails.Street, new { @class = "form-control" }) <br/>

                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.deliveryDetails.City)  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.deliveryDetails.City, new { @class = "form-control" }) <br/>

                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.deliveryDetails.State)  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.deliveryDetails.State, new { @class = "form-control" }) <br/>

                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.deliveryDetails.Postcode)  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.deliveryDetails.Postcode, new { @class = "form-control" }) <br/>

                        </div>

                        <button id="activate-step-3" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Next</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <!-- STEP 3 -->
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Card.CardHolder) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Card.CardHolder, new { @class = "form-control" }) <br />

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Card.CardNumber) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Card.CardNumber, new { @class = "form-control" }) <br />

                        <b>Card Expiry</b> <br/> <br/> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Card.ExpMonth, new { @class = "form-control" }) / @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Card.ExpYear, new { @class = "form-control" })  <br />

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Card.Cvc) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Card.Cvc, new { @class = "form-control" }) <br />

                        <input type="submit" value="Pay" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="Model" />

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now what happens is. The page is meant to have a submit button for payment to process. It sends the current Item (model) that the user is attempting to purchase (this includes its name, description, price etc.) along with other payment information, shipping information and personal details.

So the CheckoutItem contains the actual Item being sold AND the other details of the customer and the purchase etc.

The issue is, the view submits, and the code instantly goes to the parameterless constructor of this model.

Also

```
// I put in the constructor to initialize those variables in the class.
Item = new ItemModel();
```

I was told this is needed because when it grabs info, it needs an empty instance of the model to populate the information from the view.

Anyhow, what happens is, the model (for the item being sold) used to be null, after initializing as shown above, it now shows up with its default values, but it's still not really returned by the view to the controller. So the price is 0, the name and description themselves are null etc. All other payment info, personal info etc. are sent successfully in the CheckoutItem.

Another issue is this. The credit card info is simply being transferred from the returned variable of CheckoutItem to a local one in the controller, but we get a Reference Object not Instance (something along those lines) error, which you maybe familiar with. Although as you can see in the Controller, the instance of the local credit card details object have been initialized in the HttpPost method.

Any help would be appreciated to why these problems are happening. I am sure it's something not too complex that I've done somewhere that was stupid.

Thank you guys so much, you've already helped us with a problem in this project before!

Comment: Too much code: please reduce to a minimal re-create,

Comment: Are your scripts not working (what is the relevance of showing them)? What is the relevance of all that code in your POST method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The View did indeed need to have hidden fields inside the HTML form related to the Item Model so that the view knows what to submit to the controller etc as suggested by @Darin Dimitrov:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Item.ItemName)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Item.ItemPrice)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Item.ItemDescription)
...
```

The other issue with the eWay payment models/classes throwing back null errors back had to do with the fact that they had objects within objects. And if you say initialise object A, which contained object B with variables as well, then you need to initialise that instance of Object B inside A so that it's not a huge NULL value, but rather a bunch of other values. This sounds confusing, but goes as follows:

```
CustomerPayment payment1 = new CustomerPayment();
```

Now CustomerPayment objects contain another object inside, of type CreditCardDetails named CardDetails. This ALSO needs to initialize so that its variables will be accessible and the whole object isn't null, like so:

```
payment1.CardDetails = new CreditCardDetails();
```

Now you are actually able to use things inside it and assign values to them eg.:

```
payment1.CardDetails.Number = 1234 1234 1234 1234;
```

Without getting null errors back.

This is lazy coding on eWay's part (our payment gateway), providing us with classes that have parameterless constructors which don't initialise other objects encapsulated within.

Comment: Glad to see you've solved your errors! eWAY has just released a .NET library in the last couple of days to NuGet which might help, the functions you've got there don't look like they come from that (did the library come from eWAY?). Doco should be up next week, but the code is already on [GitHub](https://github.com/eWAYPayment/eway-rapid-net), it is very new and feedback is more than welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your view the only place where you use the `Item` property of your model is here:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    Item: @Model.Item.ItemName
</div>
```

Obviously that's only printing its name to the HTML. You cannot possibly expect to get back any values when you submit the data if you don't include them **inside** the HTML form.

So one possibility is to have hidden fields for them:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Item.ItemName)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Item.ItemPrice)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Item.ItemDescription)
...
```

Now those values will be sent to the server when you submit the form. The other possibility is to just fetch them from your database using the item id, the same way you did in your GET action. If the user is not supposed to modify their values this is the recommended approach.